# SQl - Intersect, Need more columns from table 1

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query that returns all records that intersects these tables but I want more columns from my table 1 (say d,e,f) but these columns are not present in table 2.

```
(select a,b,c from tab1) where d<'31-dec21'
intersect
(Select a1,b1,c1 from tab2)
```

What query should I use to get column a,b,c,d,e,f from tab1 that has a=a1,b=b1 and c=c1 in tab2?

Comment: `d<'31-dec21'` looks weird. d is a date hopefully, so you should not compare with a string that may or may not be interpreted correctly by the DBMS (depending on session settings) but with a date. A date literal looks thus: `DATE '2021-12-31'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
select a, b, c, d, e
from tab1
where (a, b, c) in (select a, b, c from tab1 where d < date '2021-12-31'
                    intersect
                    select a1, b1, c1 from tab2
                   );
```

Comment: ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns

Comment: Are you sure? Both SELECT statements in a subquery **in my example** have the same number of columns (3) so I sincerely doubt that it can raise such an error. But, **your** query might; can't tell as you didn't post it.

Comment: You are right!! I must have had it wrong when I wrote it first. This query worked fine and gave me the desired result set. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

`INTERSECT` can be rewritten to an EXISTS condition:

```
select tab1.* 
from tab1
where d < '31-dec21'
  and exists (select *
              from tab2
              where (tab1.a,tab1.b,tab1.c) = (tab2.a1,tab2.b1,tab2.c1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query does two things:

1. select all a/b/c tuples that exist in both tables
2. remove duplicates in case there are any (in contrast to `INTERSECT ALL`; see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/nfcon/details-enhanced-sql-set-operators-282451515.html on this)

You can hence select from one table and look up the rows in the other table with `IN` or `EXISTS` and then apply `DISTINCT` on the result:

```
select distinct a, b, c
from tab1 
where d < date '2021-12-31'
and (a, b, c) in (select a1, b1, c1 from tab2);
```

This enables you to select more columns from tab1 without breaking the query. Simply replace

```
select distinct a, b, c
```

by

```
select distinct a, b, c, d, e, f
```

And if it is guaranteed that there can be no duplicate (a, b, c, d, e, f) tuples in tab1, you can even remove `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
(select a,b,c,d,e,f from tab1) where d<'31-dec21'
intersect
(Select a1,b1,c1,null,null,null from tab2)
```

Comment: I get this error : ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression

Comment: My answer does not solve your problem. @Littlefoot answer is most efficient.